# DpoI do SQL Server 2014 CTP 2 OLTP in memory select statement with store procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not finding a lot of info on this question using the new OLTP in memory capability. I do know that is suggested to call stored procedures for inserts from my C# application. DO I do use a store procedure  when using a Select statement in my C#? Is a simple Select statement good enough? Are there any working examples URLs out there outside of Microsoft?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run simple ad hoc select statements, and also simple ad hoc insert statements. But you are correct that access through a natively compiled stored procedures is generally more efficient.
Ad hoc T-SQL statements on the new memory-optimized tables as well as calls to the new natively compiled stored procedures work in the same was as access to traditional tables and stored procedures. A simple example to get started is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133079.aspx

Thanks,
Jos